What is the topology of a spacelike cross-section of a null hypersurface?
I'm studying the peeling-off behaviour of zero rest-mass fields, as described in Penrose's paper. In it, he talks about the boundary $\mathscr{I}$ of the conformal completion of an asymptotically simple space. This boundary turns out to have the topology of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}^2$. My trouble comes with understanding his lemma I (page 192). If we assume that the boundary is a null hypersurface (meaning that the pullback of the metric onto the tangent space at every point of the hypersurface is degenerate), we can take a spacelike cross-section $X$ (meaning that the pullback of the metric onto the tangent space of every point of the cross-section $X$ is Riemannian, so has signature (+, +)) of this hypersurface $\mathscr{I}$. My question is the following:
Why does the condition that a cross-section $X$ of $\mathscr{I}$ is space-like make its topology that of $\mathbb{S}^2$?

The answer is somewhat silly, but I believe Penrose takes a cross-section to have the topology of $\mathbb{S}^2$ by definition. That then has nothing to do with whether or not the cross-section is spacelike. In the lemma, he just assumes that the cross-section is spacelike, rather than the cross-section being spacelike implying the topological structure.
